# Basic question about Java SecurityManager

Tags: java, junit

Over at [Custom Java SecurityManager in JUnit tests are failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814048/custom-java-securitymanager-in-junit-tests-are-failing), Randgalt asks about this code in his junits making his tests fail:

```java
    Policy.setPolicy(new Policy() {
        @Override
        public PermissionCollection getPermissions(CodeSource cs) {
            Permissions mainPermissions = new Permissions();
            mainPermissions.add(new AllPermission());
            return mainPermissions;
        }
    });
    // set a security manager so permissions get applied,
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
```

He apparently fixed his problem, but I'm hitting the same thing. I've got the above code in a @BeforeClass method, and when I run a test that tries to read a resource file from the classpath:

```java
   InputStream is = TestUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(name);
```

I get a permission check failure for

```
   ("java.io.FilePermission" "<path>/resource.xml" "read")
```

That makes the input stream come back as null and the test fails. The security manager seems to give all permissions to everything, so I don't really understand what's going on. Does "all" not really mean all?

Comment: I've found out a couple of things, though I'm a long way from fully understanding how this works. First, there's another getPermissions() method that takes in a ProtectionDomain. I'm not clear when each one is used, but they probably both need to be overridden here. Second, the checkPermission() process runs through java.security.AccessControlContext, which checks the permission against a list of ProtectionDomains. It says, "The request is allowed only if every ProtectionDomain in the context implies the permission. Otherwise the request is denied." So, my "all permission" is getting vetoed.